# Is there an equivalent/alternative to deferred.defer from Google App Engine in Django?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am looking at porting a Google App Engine app (written in Python) to Django, which is currently heavily relying on `deferred.defer` from `google.appengine.ext` to fire off high IO tasks and keep moving. Is there an equivalent/alternative to `deferred.defer` that is typically used in Django apps?

Comment: Maybe django signals and a celery client?

Comment: look at celery + django-celery.